# Number of items in a json array

Tags: javascript, json

Looking for a simple bit of JS to count the number of items in a .json file (each item represents, in this case, an instagram photo being pulled into the web app; I want to count the number of photos). Json is structured thusly...

```
{
 "type":"FeatureCollection",
 "features":[
  {
     "type":"Feature",
     "geometry":{
        "coordinates":[
           -79.40916,
           43.87767
        ],
        "type":"Point"
     },
     "properties":{
        "longitude":-79.40916,
        "latitude":43.87767,
        "title":"",
        "user":"cmay2400",
        "id":"176051485697457528_13947894",
        "image":"http:\/\/distilleryimage0.instagram.com\/1d725a3a8d7511e181bd12313817987b_7.jpg",
        "images":{
           "low_resolution":{
              "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage0.instagram.com\/1d725a3a8d7511e181bd12313817987b_6.jpg",
              "width":306,
              "height":306
           },
           "thumbnail":{
              "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage0.instagram.com\/1d725a3a8d7511e181bd12313817987b_5.jpg",
              "width":150,
              "height":150
           },
           "standard_resolution":{
              "url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage0.instagram.com\/1d725a3a8d7511e181bd12313817987b_7.jpg",
              "width":612,
              "height":612
           }
        },
        "description":"Today's ride <span class=\"tag\">#zipcar<\/span>",
        "instagram_id":"13947894",
        "likes":1,
        "profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_13947894_75sq_1322267355.jpg"
     }
  },
  {
     "type":"Feature", [...]
```

I just want to loop through the json file and count the number of items. Completely lost on where to begin.

Comment: so are we, what properties do you want to count?

Comment: Exactly what items are you trying to count?

Comment: Have you already loaded the .json file into a JS object?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Parse the JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) into an object and use it as you would any other object in JavaScript:

```
var o = JSON.parse(jsonstring);

alert(o.features.length); /* number of items in features array */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less the code you are looking for:

```
var variable = jQuery.parseJSON( stringThatIsStoringJson );

for(var i=0;i<variable.features.length;i++) {
    doStuff(variable.features[i]);

    for(var j=0;j<variable.features[i].geometry.coordinates.length;j++) {
        doMoreStuff(variable.features[i].geometry.coordinates[j]);
    }
}
```

Assuming you are using jQuery. You can parse the JSON with whatever library you want. Just avoid `eval()`, which opens your site to XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the first thing you must transform the json string into js object. by use `JSON.parse()`(IE6\7 not support) or include the Crockford's [JSON2 parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in order to support it on IE < 8.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
// loop the obj to find out what you want
```

Or another way, you can try to use some lib like [jsonSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#tryit) (CSS-like selectors for JSON.) or something like [JSONPath](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/03/17/jsonpath-support/), then you can easy to manipulate your data like:

```
var reslut = JSONSelect.match('css selector', obj);
```